# Copy specific column textbox value to another textbox in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
Table name:  editionmaster
Columns: name, edition
```

I am fetching all edition in a table using for loop, and below every edition there is a copy button.

```
Times Of India      hitwada - Dak
+------+            +------+             
| copy |            | Copy |
+------+            +------+
```

**Now I want to copy editionname to another textbox on copy button click** but the problem is that it only copies only first column editionname.

For example, if I click copy button below `timesofindia` edition, then it copies only `timesofindia` and if I click copy button below `hitwada` then it copies only hitwada to another textbox.

Please suggest me. Below is my code:

```
<tr>
    <th style="max-width:60px;"></th>
    <?php foreach($rows as $row) { ?>
        <th style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row["Edition"]; ?></th>
     <?php } ?>                       
</tr>
<tr>
    <th style="min-width:60px;">Submit</th>
    <?php foreach($rows as $row){?>
        <td> <input type=radio name=copy value='yes' id="setTimeButton" onClick="data_copy()";>copy</a></td>                      
    <?php } ?> 
</tr>    

<script type="text/javascript">
function data_copy() {
    if(document.form1.copy[0].checked){
        document.form1.Edition.value=document.form1.edition.value;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: in the second foreach you have a `<input ...` tag and you are closing it with `</a>` tag make up your mind, :).
secondly, you have not defined `form1.Edition` anywhere yet you're accessing it, consider using `document.getElementById()` function

Comment: in your code, you have not displayed where you want to copy your information to. And besides name, where is the other data that you want to copy? for the time being: http://jsfiddle.net/GME2r/